# Androids NDK does not have SUN_LEN macro

Tags: android, android-ndk

today I faced trouble - android's ndk does not have SUN_LEN macro (sys/un.h || linux/un.h ), I don't want to patch android's headers, what is better to do?

Answer (score 4):

Don't patch the headers, define it in your own file.

```
#ifndef SUN_LEN //In case they fix it down the road
#define SUN_LEN(ptr) ((size_t) (((struct sockaddr_un *) 0)->sun_path) + strlen((ptr)->sun_path))
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

SUN_LEN macro is a non-portable (aka not a part of POSIX standard) extension.
It is completely safe to use `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)` instead.