# Address already in use(errno: 98)

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk

I get a error:
Address already in use(errno:98), I use the AF_LOCAL socket, so I don't konw which is already in user the local file or local port ? 
So I should to check which port or which file is already in use?

code as below:
`

```
const char  *PATH = "/data/data/com.cxl.ipcsocket/app_local.txt";

int server_create_socket()
{
    char    buff[4096];
    int     n;
    int MAXLINE = 4096;
    int server_socket_fd, client_socket_fd;
    struct sockaddr_un server_addr;
    //Initialization socket AF_LOCAL
    if((server_socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        LOGE("server create socket error: %s(errno: %d)\n",strerror(errno),errno);
        return -1;
    }

    //Initialize sockaddr etc.
    unlink (PATH);
    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(server_addr.sun_path, PATH);

    int opt = 1;
    setsockopt(server_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, &opt,sizeof(opt));

    //Bind the Path to socket.
    if (server_bind_socket(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        LOGE("server bind socket error: %s(errno: %d)\n",strerror(errno),errno);
        return -1;
    }

    //Listen the socket
    if(server_listen_socket(server_socket_fd, 5) ==-1)
    {
        LOGE("server listen socket error: %s(errno: %d)\n",strerror(errno),errno);
        return -1;
    }

    while (1) {
        if ((client_socket_fd = server_accept_socket(server_socket_fd, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else {
                LOGE("server accept socket error: %s(errno: %d)",strerror(errno),errno);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        m_channel = client_socket_fd;
        break;
    }

    while(1){
        n = server_recive_msg(client_socket_fd, buff, MAXLINE, 0);
        //send msg to client
        if(server_send_msg(client_socket_fd, "Hello,you are connected!\n", 26,0) == -1)
        {
            perror("send error");
            LOGE("server send error: %s(errno: %d)",strerror(errno),errno);
            return -1;
        }
        buff[n] = '\0';
        printf("server recv msg from client: %s\n", buff);
    }

    LOGE("server child channel fd %d>>", m_channel);

    return 1;
    }
```

`

Comment: I work at Android NDK

Comment: In your code have you closed the socket at end ?

Comment: You need to set `server_addr.sun_len`. See here, because Android NDK does not have `SUN_LEN()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627382/androids-ndk-does-not-have-sun-len-macro

Comment: To: dhke , I add the macro as your mentioned, but the error still at here, and try the : len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len);  the error still happen.

Comment: to  user4402433, thanks, but not solve my error

Comment: You probably need to better tie your native code to the lifecycle of your Activity or Service - otherwise, you can end up trying to open the local socket a second time in response to a new lifecycle while an older one is still open, and that won't work.